# Type.GenericTypeArguments property vs Type.GetGenericArguments() method

Tags: c#, reflection, f#

What's the difference between the `Type.GenericTypeArguments` property and the `Type.GetGenericArguments()` method? Do they always return the same thing or are there situations where they differ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`typeof(List<>)` is an example where they differ. The [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.generictypearguments.aspx) returns an empty array, while the [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) returns an array with a generic `T` in it. (this `T` has [`IsGenericParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isgenericparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `true`)

From reading the documentation, I think that you can think of `GenericTypeArguments` as `GetGenericArguments().Where(t => !t.IsGenericParameter).ToArray()`, i.e. only the concrete types. See also [`ContainsGenericParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.containsgenericparameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

The reference source tells the exact answer:

```
public virtual Type[] GenericTypeArguments{
    get{
        if(IsGenericType && !IsGenericTypeDefinition){
            return GetGenericArguments();
        }
        else{
            return Type.EmptyTypes;
    }
}
```

This implementation is never overridden with something else.

Comment: I hate it when a method call is faster/simpler than a property call. Why would BCL team make this a property?